Is it possible for an overly frugal culture to have high economic growth?
The culture in question is a highly religious one, and has more or less shrugged off three centuries worth of secularization campaigns due to how strong their religious structures are. One of their many important dogmas are over the importance of preserving resources for the next generation, abhorring overt luxuries, and hiding your wealth to protect yourself from envy and "weakness".
This also means that they will save every penny they can, only ever investing it in business or their children's future. They even keep their food bland and nutritious to show off about how frugal and religious they are, and boast about how they buy their stuff as cheap as possible. It's a culture obsessed with one-upping each other about saving money, among other things.
With that said, they do like having more money, but mostly try to cast it as just "hard work". While luxuries are a no-no, having lots of money can still buy you power and respect as long as you use it the right way. Getting your children in the right colleges and donating to the right places, for example.
But to return to the main topic, will such a consumption averse culture be able to industrialize? In first world countries, consumption of "luxury" products like tobacco, sugar, and spices were critical in driving commerce and creating capitalism. Without high consumer spending, there would be practically no way of creating enough private commerce to create a modern economy. Everyone would just keep hiding their wealth and eventually drive the country to stagnation.
Or am I misunderstanding economics, and it's possible for prudent investment to raise economic growth?

Incidentally, are your people dedicated to their society at large being modest, or just individuals?  Do they, for example, construct ornate cathedrals, fine fountains for the public squares, etc?

@Jedediah Their construction is usually simplistic. Temples are mostly a community affair, and they can vary from glorified cowsheds to terrifying behemoths out of a dystopian novel. Their architecture is just as ruthlessly pragmatic, and there's very little ornamentation.

Too short to be an answer, but: economic growth often comes from efficiency, e.g. improving a process so that it takes fewer resources often causes an increase in consumption of those resources because it's now more economic to use them than it was before. And economic efficiency is not at all at odds with frugalism, they should go hand in hand.

Do you know about Calvinism (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protestant_work_ethic)? It seems a perfect fit for an actual historical example of what you are looking for. Also check out the book by Max Weber for a more detailed explanation.

...and boast about how they buy their stuff as cheap as possible. It's a culture obsessed with one-upping each other about saving money, among other things. Sounds like the Dutch. That said, buying things cheap can be the most expensive option, as a good product can last longer than the lifespan of multiple inferior ones bought for the same price. While having to replace a product constantly would be good for the ones selling that product, it will be against their tenet of preserving resources (in the long run).

The question seems to assumes luxury consumption is required to maintain capitalism, capitalism is the only way to achieve industrialization, industrialization is the only way to achieve economic growth, and economic growth is the defining characteristic of a 'modern economy'. Just because these relationships hold in the currently dominant culture on the planet, it doesn't follow that they are universal requirements.

According to the Washington Post, China is a pretty good example of such a country. Everyone seems to want to increase consumption.

religious and high economic growth will not be sustainable, long term economic growth relies on inovation, which does not get along well with dogma.

There are potential problems with the scenario that other answers have noted, but with that said, prioritizing investment over consumption is great for economic growth. In economics terms, your society prioritizes investing in capital goods over consumer goods, which shifts the PPF curve outwards, increasing the production potential of your economy. What will kill your economy is hoarding rather than investing.
You do have a slight conflict between investing large sums and your stated goal of hiding your wealth. To make your scenario work, your society almost certainly needs a very well-developed and discreet banking system, Switzerland-style. (Edit in response to comment: the goal is to not show off wealth, rather than actually hide it. However, a good banking system is still important for economic development.) This both resolves the problem and can make investment more efficient. Your economy also has to be driven very heavily by exports, otherwise beyond a certain point there's simply no point in further development.

100% Agreed. The potential pitfall of an investment-minded, 100% frugal economy is that without luxury spending on non-essentials, the economy has no cushion for the times of demand crash. Luxury spending tends to persist and create an artificial demand, because most common luxury goods are addictive in some way. Even in the worst times of economic depression, people still buy booze, cigarettes, sugar, sex etc. The last liquor store outlives the last bakery, because some people prefer to go hungry rather than sober, and that at least keeps the liquor industry (and its employees) afloat.

@GoingDurden I'm not sure how much that applies to this economy. As described, demand can't crash, or rather it's permanently crashed. That means either that development is very limited, or that supply soon far exceeds demand, which means export. If exports fall, that impacts profits, and therefore investment, but not really the internal economy. Demand doesn't change, it's already at a minimum, and supply still exceeds demand. Prices could go up internally, but if everything is invested anyway, what's the difference?

demand can absolutely crash in a frugal economy. Say, if the word gets out that LED lights are more cost efficient than traditional lightbulbs, the demand for lightbulbs will drop to zero overnight. Perfect frugality means that supply is exactly tuned to the demand, maximum demand is exactly equal to minimum demand, and that demand is total (ie: everyone agrees lightbulbs are frugal enough so everyone buys them) and then suddenly drops to zero (everyone learns that LEDs are better and switch).
Investment means LEDs will be invented sooner, and the switch will be more abrupt.

@GoingDurden "Perfect frugality means that supply is exactly tuned to the demand" - For an exporting economy (which a developed AND frugal economy has to be pretty much by definition), that's not necessarily true. If there's no trade, it's probably never going to develop traditional lightbulbs, let alone LEDs. But in any case you're describing a micro- rather than a macroeconomic drop in demand. The demand for lighting is unchanged and the switch will happen precisely at the point where production of LEDs is enough to match demand. A company might go broke but the economy is fine.

When I say they "hide" their wealth, it means they just don't advertise their bank account by buying mansions or yachts. However, investing your money in business would be considered a good thing because it means you're doing honest work and spreading your wealth around. So would investing in your children's education or health, because that just shows how good a father you are.

@Thales So, not so much "hiding" as "not flashing"? I don't know that that changes much, except that costs of education and healthcare (as the "legitimate" ways to show off your wealth) will be inflated. You still need exports as the motivation to drive development and you still pretty much need a strong banking system.

@user111403 They don't really have any problems with trade, one way or another. As long as there are no drugs or "obscene media" being imported, the religious authorities are completely apathetic to it.

As a simpler way of thinking about it, "economic growth" is an increase in the ability of the economy to provide people with what they want and/or consuming less of the most valuable precursors to do so.  The contents of the "what they want" though, is a matter of taste. So if they eschew creature comforts for religious reasons, that doesn't really matter much. The economic growth will simply focus on whatever objectives they do want to accomplish and they'd do more of those with less effort instead.

One can still produce voluptuary goods and sell them to outside of their group, without owning any of those frowned upon goods.
It's not that different from how capitalism work today, just sprinkled with religious motivations: luxury goods are not produced in the countries where they are purchased, but rather in some places where workforce is cheap.

Would that be enough to drive economic growth?

@Thales Assuming you are in the U.S., the vast majority of what you buy is made in China. Even if China internally had a very frugal culture, do you think they would experience no economic growth from the massive manufacturing industry required to keep the U.S. supplied with cheap goods?

@user45623 Before China in the 2000's, we had Japan for e.g. automobiles and electronics. See what happened there.

@user71659 An export economy drives economic growth; it does not guarantee perpetual economic growth forever. The decline in the Japanese economy has been driven by several factors, but one of the precipitating factors was increased costs, e.g. due to Japanese workers wanting higher wages. One factor that drives wages (and therefore costs) in developed countries is the desire to purchase luxury goods. In the hypothetical extremely frugal nation, a lack of luxury spending would mean much less demand for higher wages, keeping costs down, keeping the nation very competitive for manufacturing.

Yes, easy enough
Far from all consumer spending is on luxuries, and far from all opportunities for investment are in consumer goods.

investing it in business or their children's future

If you think about it, what is investment? It's a way of shifting money from where it is not needed today (in this case, a household with surplus income) to where it is needed today (a business seeking capital). Investment only works if it's a win-win - the business is able to earn more money than it borrowed, and return some of that money to the investor in the form of interest on the debt.
This is the case in even frugal (by culture or necessity) societies, such as command economies. Under Lenin, one of the ways the USSR funded industrialization was through joint-stock societies, for example Dobrolet below.

Even after the NEP was replaced with collectivization, citizens were encouraged to keep their savings in the bank, where they could accrue interest. The caption on this posted explicitly calls out that doing this supports agricultural development.

There was plenty of money to save, because (outside of major cities) there was often nothing to buy. And yet the Soviet economy still grew.
Investment into things other than luxuries
So if the Soviet economy wasn't driven by luxury consumption, what was it driven by?
Two main things: military spending, and providing basic needs.
Your military-industrial complex is always going to be growing. Even if the number of soldiers stays the same, research into new weapons is ongoing. That research requires fundamental research into physics and chemistry. The more complex these things get (think electronics) the more industry is needed to support it, which means more workers, and therefore more service industries such as food, transport, education...
In parallel, growing populations also require more resources. The USSR spent lavishly on the "Virgin Lands Campaign" (turning Siberian wastes into productive farmland) and "Transformation of Nature" (irrigation, forestry, etc).
All of these industries can turn tremendous profit for investors (or dismal failure that wipes out savings).
Investment into the children
Since your society is not a Communist state, there is also a great opportunity to invest in all the industries that pop up around child-rearing. Until kids leave their parents' homes, they consume a lot of services:

Education (top private schools can cost as much as college)
Extra-curricular activities like sports teams or summer camps to build physical health and good character
Tutors (for the exams to get into the top schools, or to teach them culturally valuable skills like musical instruments)
Medicine and nutrition (kids get sick or hurt all the time, and even if your kid is not sickly, a robust course of vitamins will keep their health up)

You can absolutely live a materially frugal lifestyle and yet wear your alma mater as a badge of pride. And Oxford needs investment too...
Vimes Theory of Boots
But that doesn't mean we can't also have some luxury consumption, if we take "luxury" to mean "nice stuff."

A man who could afford fifty dollars had a pair of boots that’d still be keeping his feet dry in ten years’ time, while the poor man who could only afford cheap boots would have spent a hundred dollars on boots in the same time and would still have wet feet.

In the long run, buying junk will cost you more money. Not just replacing boots, but (for example) expensive medical treatment as a consequence of cheaping out on your doctor. Not very frugal! Instead, true cheapskates brag about the longevity of their possessions.
Similarly, a tool that saves you an hour per day pays for itself very quickly because you can use that extra hour to do more work.
Which means that there will be a certain floor of quality in the items available for sale, and that floor will always be rising as innovations in design, material science, etc lead to longer lasting, more effective - and naturally, more expensive - products.

No, it's a totalitarian setting. It's just that most people are part of the Proles, and only the Outer Party have to worry about the dystopian surveillance and other forms of "direct" oppression. The general public is perfectly capable of oppressing itself without too much aid from the government.

Going for longevity is the idea. Using more scarce resources sparingly, and being repairs/maintenance friendly is important too. Japanese Wood Joinery is a great example for frugal use of non-renewable resources. In this craft (next to) no nails or glue is used. buildings following this craft can reasonably withstand earthquakes, are very maintenance friendly, easy to replace, and are currently often part of the longest lasting wooden building in the world.

Upvoted for using Vimes' Boots as a lesson in WISE frugality.

Worth remembering that Pratchett isn't an economist.

Kinda possible, but difficult.
The problem here is, the frugality cannot extend to being investment-shy: the Frugals still need to put their hoarded money to use, otherwise its not arguably money at all, just worthless tokens.
As much as it pains me to write it, the best solution here is TAXATION. Have the Frugals pay absurd taxes, like 80%+ of their income, or some structure that siphons wealth away from their savings in a progressive manner.
Then, the government (which we can only hope is made of 100% honest Frugals, and not crooks) uses the extra money to invest in the infrastructure, education, industry, technological progress and science. The Frugals are still frugal as ever, but economic growth (and with it, technological and industrial progress) would make them more efficient at being frugal.
For example, fanatical Frugals should support the country moving from fossil fuels to renewable energy, because in the long term it is more cost-saving, even if it requires an investment upfront.
As long as the idea of frugality is interpreted intelligently (thinking long-term, rational choices, investing in progress now to save money later etc) this can work, but the system would be very vulnerable to two risks:
1 - Fanatical Fiscally-Conservative Frugals winning the elections (or whatever form of governance they have) and strangling public works investments
2 - Overly Liberal Post-Frugals winning the elections, and over-investing to the point of debt, putting the country in a downwards spiral.
"Luxury spending" is not what drives the economy, but it often works like a "cushion" that helps ease economic hiccups. When all citizens are frugal, the economy is always finely tuned to follow practical supply and immediate demand, which means that businesses immediately fold and die the moment they find themselves in a dip. But as long as people buy things the irrationally desire, rather than rationally need, "luxury" businesses can stay afloat even through the worst economic depression. When the economy is in shambles, its often the liquor store that folds last, long after the bakery and the doctor's office closed, because non-frugal people will rather face the economic apocalypse drunk than sober. People spending money on non-essentials is a "trickle sideways" economy, that forces the circulation of wealth, even when they do not need to, and prevents the frugality from causing a Tragedy of the Commons.
Without this "cushion", the government needs to step up and manipulate supply, demand, and the job market by inventing public works of some kind, even if it was just digging holes and filling them back again. And for that, it needs ....taxes.

I don't believe massive taxation is the only or best way (see my answer), it's both less stable, as you noted, and less efficient, but it is a way it could work. +1

@user111403, It is hard to say, without more details on how the Frugal Culture works and what are its tenets. By view is that if every citizen there is a fanatically frugal investor, they will just focus on local optimization at the cost of everything else, which will quickly collapse the economy, then the infrastructure, and finally the environment. It ends up with a network of fiefdoms of rich, but cheapskate libertarian overlords who optimized the system to death, with the rest of the economy, and thus, society with its people, deemed "unnecessary spending" and truncated.

They're not investment shy, they actually love investment and watching the line go up. What they hate is the idea of people flaunting their wealth, because they have been trained to think of those people as immoral and disgusting. It's more about "virtue and discipline" than any sense of egalitarianism, though. They're no less stratified than any other theocracy.

They're human, they still love megastructures and grandiose construction projects. It's just that the governments try to keep to big construction projects that have an obvious practical use. Like roads, or flood walls, or massive irrigation networks.
Boasting about having the longest canals or biggest power plants isn't as psychologically cathartic as boasting about big palaces or temples, but they have to make do.

So this goes to the core of economics, and you need to approach it from the direction of understanding how an economy works, and what makes its optimization functions tick.  This is going to be difficult for most schools of economic thought, since most of them are focused on determining how best to manipulate an economy to achieve a government's objectives, rather than on achieving a deep understanding of what happens in a free economy and why.
Fortunately, it's actually very simple.

Human beings "act".  By that we mean that they take in information about the world, the available resources, and the available objectives, and they take decisions about how to allocate their resources to accomplishing objectives.
Human beings are "rational".  That doesn't mean they're like Mr. Spock.  And that doesn't mean that they never make mistakes.  It just means that they allocate their resources first to whatever they deem most valuable, to themselves, at that precise moment.  Their choices might seem silly to you, or even insane, but that's not the same as "irrational."

From these two, simple observations, one can derive several thousand pages of analysis about what people as a group are likely to do when and why.  We don't really need to dive into the whole thing for this, but if you're going to be super serious about devising working cultures and economies in your worldbuilding then I'd recommend "Man, Economy, and State", by Murray Rothbard.
For this particular question, you need only look at what you're actually changing.  And, really, it's not all that much.
They focus on cost rather than "creature comforts."  So then, rather than putting their effort into importing spices from far-off lands or trucking fresh fruit from the other side of the equator to have it year-round they're going to focus their energies on finding the most efficient way to have a balanced diet while expending the minimum amount of fuel, labor, land, or whatever other resources end up being the bottleneck for food production.
Similarly, they're likely to focus their building energies on pure functionality with little regard for artistry. Making things look pretty is a luxury.
None of this precludes economic growth.  Just the opposite really.  Finding ways to turn less valuable resources into more valuable resources is the core of economic growth, and finding clever ways to do more with less is the core of frugality.  They align very nicely.  The only thing your culture will do differently is it will have a higher incidence of people stopping to ask, "Do I really need that?" before committing to it.  They may have less overall as a result, but they're likely to be more satisfied with what they do have.  And satisfaction of wants is a much better measurement of economic power than currency units spent or anything like that.  It's just a lot harder to quantify, so nobody uses it as a metric.  But they probably won't care about that, since precise measurement of economic power isn't actually something most people have any reason to need or want.
If you want to know where most of their economic growth will be, then you need to look at what they do want to accomplish with their lives, rather than what they don't.  You mentioned investment in business and their children's future as being things they like.  Prioritizing long-term investment over short-term consumption is a great way to power economic growth.  As long as the things they're investing in producing are things they want.  Which goes back to the first two principles.  People generally won't willingly or intentionally invest in things that run contrary to what they want.
So, industrialization?  Yes.  Definitely.  Industrialization is absolutely critical to improving your children's futures.  Prior to the industrial revolution the number one cause of death for human beings was starvation and malnutrition.  No parent is going to be happy with the 50-80% child mortality rate that was the norm in pre-industrial civilization.  They're going to have a big focus on producing more food, clothing, and shelter, and that takes better tools, and better tools to build tools to build tools...  Eventually it reaches critical mass and poof!  There's your Industrial Revolution.
After that?  After everyone's fed and clothed and has enough housing?  Well...  What do they want next?  I'd guess their religion has something to say about goals.  Like, they need to be frugal and save...  But what are they saving for?
Just for disaster recovery?  They'll bust their butts to have emergency shelters and reserves of supplies. Building self-sufficient colonies on other continents, and then on other planets, and then around different stars will be a priority for them to minimize the chances of a single disaster wiping everybody out.
Because physical things distract from spiritual things?  Expect them to invest piles of time and energy into their spiritual sides.  They might not build all the fancy, physical toys that we do, but you should see their libraries and universities.
Once you start thinking about the economy as an engine for satisfying wants, rather than for meeting arbitrary GDP targets and all that nonsense, then your definition of "growth" becomes coherent and you can get down to the actually interesting question of figuring out what kind of growth is going to happen.  Their desire to invest in their children and make the next generation better definitely points toward growth.  You just have to figure out what "better" looks like.  Because value is subjective.  The only thing with "intrinsic value" is a human being, and that's because human beings tend to value themselves.  Everything else is just funny plants and worthless rocks until some person decides they have a use for it.

I love this question!
Yes, it's possible for such a society to enjoy a strong economy
First, let's dispel a myth. A strong economy is not an economy where everyone is rich. It's an economy where everyone is employed and has access to their needs and many of their wants. What you've done is changed the list of "wants" dramatically and the list of "needs" somewhat...
...but not completely!
It's a fundamental truth that all the gold in the world is useless if there isn't a use for it or someone willing to trade you something for it. Therefore, there must still be a purpose for the wealth or the act of creating it won't produce status. Ask yourself, "how impressed would people be if I possessed the world's largest amount of autumn leaves?" Answer: other than the few people who stop to see the world's largest ball of string, etc., not a single soul on Earth. Autumn leaves don't have enough intrinsic value and nobody is going to trade you a thing for them.
What this all means is that the goods being bought and the industries enjoying investment are different from what we're used to in our own societies... but they're still there.
Wealth brings power
OK, what does that mean? You can hire more bodyguards than your neighbor? You can donate more to support your favorite political leader? Simplifying things to the point where angels weep, power brings you (a) the physical ability to act (to enforce your will or defend yourself) and (b) the ability to grease the proverbial wheels (invest in business, politics, to be an "influencer"). The kinds of industries that use this kind of investment include:

Police, military, and security.
Politicians and sociopolitical advertising (swaying people's opinions).1
Education and indoctrination.
Art and entertainment.2

And there's a regular need for...

Religious supplies.
Political paraphernalia (like photos of the Ecumenical Elite and flags to wave during Blessed Holidays).

But more importantly...

Regardless how bland the food, every house needs water coming in and sewer going out with regular innovation to make those services more efficient and capable.
Roads need to be built and maintained.
Emergency services must be provided.
Taxes must be collected.
Farms require seeds and fertilizer.
And all the equipment those people, services, and businesses need...

There are a LOT of places for people to invest their money and the size and nature of those investments bring status. Your society needs vehicles (whether trucks or carts+horses) just to move things around... that's a pretty good business and being known for having the most reliable service is something to be proud of!
Yeah, yeah, yeah... but how do I really show off my wealth?
It's been a really, really, really long time since I read The Scarlet Letter, but if I recall, one character distinguished himself from the crowd by wearing lace. My point? There are plenty of ways to subtly demonstrate wealth while remaining outwardly pious.

Clothing quality
Cleanliness
Cutlery
Carpet, draperies and wall coverings
And a lot of things that don't begin with the letter "C"

I remember reading a book many years ago where in a society that embraced austerity and simplicity (households were furnished to a level that most of us would consider unreasonably scant) a family's wealth was demonstrated by the fact that the one vase allowed for decoration in a room was different, each and every day.
People are always going to find a way to spend their money, it just depends on how
I've had many talks with business owners and retail managers about the issue of why people don't visit their store. My favorite reason is, "people are cheap! All they want is cheap! Nobody in this community has money to spend!" It's easy to see this perspective, but it's wrong! Even in the poorest neighborhoods there's profit to be made so long as you have the right products and are willing to be patient.3
From a worldbuilding perspective, you have a controlled society with a set of mores that precludes what we Westerners would normally consider the trappings of wealth. But ours is a so-called "free society" wherein we can pretty much get anything we want without government interference. In your world the government interferes. So one of the questions you should be asking is, "what would my government want people to spend their money on?" When you set aside the necessities of life (e.g. utilities, food, housing, emergency and essential services) what is the government willing to let people take pride in? Music? Sport? Jobs? Perhaps one of the most significant signs of wealth and influence is the number of people you employ....
How is wealth stored?
Sometimes we get stuck on the kind of wealth we have today. Principally, money. We imagine wealth in terms of a big pile of dollar bills with us sitting atop it. The imagery led to the Ann Margret/Oprah Photo Controversy and The Joker sliding down a pile of money. But stuffing the proverbial mattress full of cash is just one way to store wealth. Today we can own real estate or precious metals or a fancy car... all kinds of things! How would this happen in your society? Hold that thought!
Finally, I have one word for you, just one word: Exports

In 2022, Israel exported $49.3k in Pig Meat, making it the 87th largest exporter of Pig Meat in the world. (Source)4

Just because your society doesn't consume a particular commodity or product doesn't necessarily mean that such a creature doesn't exist. If we see jobs as a potential sign of wealth in your society, then employing the very best horologists and exporting the beautiful things they make would definitely stimulate your economy.
Exports my friend. Exports.
So one way to store (and show off) your wealth is to have a honking big warehouse full of goods ready to ship to your barbarian neighbors.
And the fact that you never seem to have less than a full warehouse filled with ostentatious things is patiently overlooked by your religious leadership because it's generating taxes each and every year....

1 And yes, even in a religious totalitarian state, there's the need to sway people's opinions. Even if you're investing in the business of making big banners that say "BLESSED ARE THE OBEDIENT!"
2 Religious and/or totalitarian governments have only a few ways to keep the population content, and a content population is very important! One may not approve of ostentatious entertainment (no Las Vegas showgirls in this community!) but that doesn't mean there isn't delight and even pride in cultural presentations of all kinds. Who wouldn't enjoy seeing a state-sponsored, priest-blessed, and very tightly controlled version of The Great Dictator with just enough satire to relieve societal stress but not enough to get people really thinking? Am I right?
3 Inevitably, at this point in the aforementioned discussion with business owners and retail managers they roll their eyes and say something like, "anybody can make money if you're selling drugs and prostitutes!" They missed the point, which is why their stores are having trouble. Start asking yourself (and I mean that... you... the worldbuilder), what do people really need? What do people really want? If you're trying to be the best pizza place out of six what you might not realize is that people want chicken — but I guarantee you they want something and they're willing to pay for it.
4 In the world of economics, that "k" can have different meanings. Sometimes there's a note someplace that says (e.g.) "numbers in millions." If that's the case (although I couldn't find such a note) that export might be \$49 Billion. Or it might really be a whopping \$49,000. The amount isn't as relevant as the fact that a culture that does not eat pork for strict religious purposes is perfectly happy to export it to others.

This question is best answered by looking at some of the frugal religious communities in this country. Not only are they frugal, but they are also conservative about ideas. Strong religions are averse to new ideas.
Industrialization started by people with new ideas. New ideas generated more new ideas and new processes, new products, new technologies, etc. There is a reason why a place that accepts new ideas is more likely to be the source of industrial progress. Industrial progress happens by a lot of crazy ideas, fast fortunes quickly lost, failed companies, bankruptcies, and other things that a conservative religious group would frown upon.
Edit: When new ideas or new industries threaten the income or status of established people, they will push back with whatever power they can. In a society with a strong religion, that push back will be done via religion. So, they will urge the inquisition to investigate the new teachings or burn books, etc. (When they have political power, they will use that - see zoning cases, municipal ordinances, and Prohibition. When violence is the only power they have, they will use that, e.g. KKK.) It is not that religion is inherently antagonistic to new ideas, but that people with money and power who are threatened by new ideas and industries will use religion to protect themselves.
Once an industrial progress has been shown to be highly profitable, then a strongly religious group may invest in it or allow members to partake in it. Almost all the industrial progress will come from outside, not generated internally.
The strongly religious culture will advance behind its neighbors and only adopt things a generation or two later. It will not have high economic growth by itself.
Edit:
Let me give an example from two cities. Longview Texas is in the middle of one of the largest oil fields found in America. Lots of people made a lot of money from that oil. But that money did not stay in the community to build up a diverse economy. Contrast that with Houston which is far more accepting of new ideas. Houston boomed while Longview stayed the same.

"Strong religions are averse to new ideas" - this is a stereotype that it's disappointing to see repeated here. There was lots of scientific development in Christian Europe throughout its history, and among Muslims in the Middle Ages. Many early industrialists as well as great scientists were deeply religious. For many people, religion, far from contradicting science, gave them a philosophical basis for science. Is it possible for a religion to be frugal and against progress - sure, but they don't have to go together.

Yes, many early industrialists and scientists were strongly religious. But the purpose of religion is to uphold and preserve the social order. Industrial progress inevitably creates new wealth which upsets the social order. If that progress is done slowly, then it is welcomed by religion.

A purpose (not the purpose) of religion may be to uphold the social order, but this isn't always true. Many teachings in Christianity were extremely radical in the first century (early on, contrary to modern stereotypes, it was mocked as a "religion of women and slaves"). Religion is not inherently opposed to social mobility. The fact is that we have precisely one real-world example of an industrial revolution, and it started in a society with very strong Christian influence.

@DavidR Religion does not exist to preserve social order, but to satisfy the wants, needs, and fears of people.  One side-effect of this is a greater social order, but it can also lead to a greater curiosity about the world around us as it adds personal value to understanding for understanding sake. Despite the modern narrative, practically all of the major scientific advancements from the time of the Ancient Greeks all the way through the mid-20th century was overwhelmingly comprised of exceptionally religious people who desired a better understanding of their gods and creation.

There is a forum for debating religion and this isn't it. Having said that, Christianity was not an established religion in the 1st century and the bible as we know it didn't exist until the 4th century. Christianity is a good example of a religion that is not open to new ideas. Hint "Protestant" - one who protests against the church!

@PaulSmith when an answer is based on inaccurate stereotypes, that needs to be addressed. As you say, this isn't the forum for religious debates, so I won't respond in detail, but don't confuse acceptance of new doctrinal ideas and new scientific or technological ideas.

@user111403 and don't confuse acceptance of a new scientific or technological idea among a small group of people with wide acceptance of a technological idea generating major new industries upsetting the social order. One can be tolerated and the new ideas might slowly seep into the culture over several generations. The other generates a backlash by those whose incomes and social positions are challenged.

"The other generates a backlash by those whose incomes and social positions are challenged" - that's both obviously true and also nothing to do with religion. The people on top in any society will push back against any change that will shift too many of them off the top too quickly.

It's absolutely possible to construct a religion opposed to new technology - we have plenty of real-world examples. But the assumption that religion must be opposed to technology, and that a strongly religious society will lag behind its neighbors in economic development, is both not well-founded in theory and just falls flat when we look at empirical real-world evidence. I'm not going to debate further.

@user111403 - Now who is using inaccurate stereotypes? Religion does not oppose technology, the default position of any religion is to maintain the status quo, and that means to oppose change, regardless of whether it is social, political or technological,   until such time as that change becomes the new status quo. There are exceptions, most of which derive from the English Nonconformists, but they are notable for being exceptions.

@PaulSmith Protestants are actually protesting against the excesses of the Catholic church, particularly with respect to indulgences, but also because of the political power that Church possessed. The assorted Princes of Europe backed these "Protestants" for primarily political reasons.

@PaulSmith the NT Scriptures that we know now were much earlier than 4th century, just the Canon list was universally recognized then, but we have evidence they were written in the 1st century, and a lot of quotes from them through the first centuries.

Investments
An economy does not actually need consumerism. Your people could instead:

Invest in industrial capacity (like factories)
Invest in R&D and technological development
Invest in basic sciences
Invest in machine learning
Buy up businesses in other countries
etc...

From an outside perspective, it would look almost like Factorio or something: factories produce resources mainly for the factory owners to build new factories, instead of for luxuries. There is trade between these factory owners but in the end it all goes towards more factories (plus a little bit of advanced farming equipment so you can pay for labor, but you don't need too much labor because you have automation).
Consumerism will only arise if someone rich actually wants it. In theory a rich factory owner could stop building factories and build and staff a luxury yacht instead, but as you mentioned your religion discourages this.
In this economy, most of the labor goes towards factory workers, engineers, and scientists.

I think this sounds like a culture that shuns certain parts of a typical pyramid of needs, while emphasizing others to the extreme. The important part is that there are still needs, and those needs will still never be perfectly achieved so the economy has to grow infinitely without ever fully satisfying those needs.

I would say the bottom three parts of the pyramid are definitely important in your society, the physiological, safety, and love needs are oneself and ones children are considered important. Esteem needs are shunned and self-actualisation-needs might or might not be shunned.
The bottom of the pyramid alone (physiological needs) is enough to drive an economy infinitely, I will just list some economic/technological advancements that are needed to fulfil the physiological needs in roughly the order where they become important:

achieve food security: learn how to efficiently do acriculture (instead of just foraging), store food, tell apart unsafe food and safe food
have a shelter available that keeps you safe even if you can't work for sometime: build a house, with a fireplace, stores of everything you need to live for a while
try to stay healthy: learn about germ theory, get running water, soap, canalisation.
to be able to get everyone the above, you need a pretty massive economy already, but probably still pre-industrial
have a public health system where people can get treated if they have accidents or get ill
start a nation wide scheme to ensure food security and the basic needs of everyone
have a pension system
probably industrialization will start around here, because a health system and pension system is just not feasible in a more basic economy
discover more about health research, vaccines, sun lotion, start really investing in education
try to eradicate all of the common illnesses that modern society has eradicated in our world
health alone can drive a society far beyond our current modern society, after all we still have a lot of uncurable illnesses and basically every technology that exists has some applications in medicine

In parallel there might also economic growth driven by safety needs:

Protect against wildlife: another reason for houses, first weapons
Protect against violent crime: have some justice system (expensive, needs efficiency improvements to finance those people ensuring justice instead of growing food or whatever)
Protect against attacks from other nations/groups: Well, you can invent all the weapons in the world with that justification, purely for defensive needs of course.
Notice that it might be cheaper to help other nations with their basic needs and economic development rather than fighting them, start development aid, conflict mediation, etc.

And regarding the love needs:

You need some free time to really fullfil those needs. This needs efficiency improvements to be possible.
If you are really looking out for your children you might also want to spend more and more time raising children, which also requires efficiency improvements so one parent can sustain the family's material needs while the other tends to the kids.


Saving their Money.
The money is saved to a fund managed by the Holy Church. Its stated purpose is to:

Send missionaries to for'n lands to bring the sinners to enlightenment.
Aid in international negotiations to prevent the unworthy getting the upper hand.
Relieve starvation/sickness (but only to the extent that life is preserved, no "luxury" foods).
Train converts to the highest standards of frugality and modesty.
Ensure that the funds are there when they're needed for the day of calling (ie. The One Church stockpiles cash/kind), that all worthy souls are able to be anointed in the most holy oils and that all are suitably shriven before ascension.
"Convincing" the perceived enemies of The One Church that the Church's way is the only way (by whatever means).

Naturally, the church invests and runs the economy for the benefit of the most holy way and those who follow that path.
This should involve all the usual things; trade agreements, arranging suitable marriages, spying, bribery, conscripting soldiers and hiring mercenaries to fight wars, ensuring that only the most worthy are in positions of power in society, and that The One Church thrives without too-much competition.

being frugal is the main driver of economic growth.  specifically you state "investing it in business or their children's future", which is the absolutely best way to encourage long-term economic growth.  the vast majority of "industrialization" was not driven by luxury items.  things like steam engines were developed for mining, textiles, manufacturing and travel. none of those are typically considered luxury goods. a society like the one you describe would have a substantially higher economic growth rate than any real society ever could because they would devote all their energy to becoming more productive. one way to look at it is that in order to "invest in their children's future", they might focus simply on reducing the probability that their decedents would starve to death. the best way to do that would be to accumulate wealth and develop technology to turn that wealth into basic necessities as efficiently as possible. another way to look at it would be to compare it to the current first-world obsession with healthcare spending.  that is generally not considered a luxury, but it is a limitless target for investment that pays out societal dividends by keeping people in the workforce who would otherwise be in a grave.

Frugal folks are forced to put their hoarded funds to some kind of productive use by inflation.
By the government effectively stealing a few percent every year the saver sees their  savings decrease in buying power (and they are likely taxed at maximum rate on any risk-free interest on their savings).

Expanding on some thoughts I mentioned in comments:
The hypothetical nation you've described would function beautifully as an export economy - one driven largely by exporting goods to other nations.
China is a prime example of an export economy. In many countries, most of the goods you purchase are manufactured in China. Why? Because China has a huge manufacturing industry and low costs. Massive amounts of money flow from countries like the U.S. into China each year to produce goods. This is a huge driver of economic growth.
Our hypothetical nation of frugality has several advantages that would help it maintain an edge as an export economy:

Since the citizens spend little or no money on luxuries, they would not have as much incentive to demand higher wages. Employees won't be looking for a pay raise so they can afford the latest iPhone, car, or gaming console. This helps keep manufacturing costs down.
Less interest in luxury spending means fewer strikes for
Because consumer spending is always low, there's less risk of economic turmoil caused by sudden changes in spending habits (however, the economy would still be vulnerable to external factors, e.g. if the U.S. has a major recession and suddenly wants to import fewer goods). Less economic turmoil means less risk of disruption to manufacturing.
When there's a downturn in the economy because of external factors (other countries are buying less goods), it's easier for both companies and individuals to absorb the downturn by using some of their savings. This means less economic turmoil and less risk of companies going bankrupt.
Citizens who are not motivated to acquire wealth in order to purchase luxury goods are much less likely to make risky or overzealous investments, which again means less risk of economic turmoil.


The big problem with this culture is that without luxury there is only stagnation.
Everything we consider "basic living standard" today once started as a luxury. Electricity started as a luxury, today it is a "basic need". Water from the tap was a luxury and going to the local well was the standard, until the luxury spread more and more and now you would frown upon someone without water in their home.

"In modern Britain we're lucky to be able to take it for granted that our homes have a constant supply of clean and safe running water.
However, when the first major domestic water supply system was built in London in the 1600s, it was a luxury reserved for only the wealthiest sections of society."

source: https://www.museumofthehome.org.uk/explore/stories-of-home/a-brief-history-of-running-water/

If Edison brought electric lights to the rich, then Insull brought electricity to everyone.

source: https://earlybirdelectricians.com/blog/electricity-history/

to some extent, especially during the period 1880–1890, electrical lighting was considered a luxury product

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_electric_power_transmission
A culture that forbids luxury is doomed to stagnate and soon be surpassed by other cultures in terms of living standards.

Any source on those technologies being considered luxuries?

This is easily addressed through pure utilitarianism. Water delivered through pipes unlocks far greater industrial efficiency. Even on the domestic front, an economy that places more demands on citizens' time that they need to live (shop for food, sleep, tend to children, obtain medical services) is an economy that runs out of people. Electricity allows for less time to be spent on maintaining the home, and therefore more time on the workplace.

The question puts a lot of emphasis on looking out for future generations and economic growth for the sake of it, "investing it in business or their children's future". The things that once were luxuries and now are basic needs are all things that make future generations lifes better/safer/longer and are good investments. For example being frugal probably doesn't mean accepting that you die young, it means spending your money on cancer research instead of cigarettes.

@Thales I added quotes and sources for both

@SPavel that is true, however any invention that has the goal of making "life better" is a luxury at the start. "luxury: great comfort, especially as provided by expensive and beautiful things" also "luxury: something expensive that is pleasant to have but is not necessary" both from https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/luxury this means that the society has conflicting goals. Making the life better IS luxury

@Nobody but the question also highlights that the people want to be SEEN as non-luxurious. "They even keep their food bland and nutritious to show off" And most inventions that better the lifes start as a "unneccessary luxury". Ask someone in 1980s if they NEED a computer. Ask someone in 1880 if they NEED electricity. They didn't need it, they wanted it, but they didn't need it.

@datacube In the 1980s people didn't "have" computers like today, organisations had them. And yes a frugal society definitely needs faster and more correct calculations for things like health care, pension system, banking, etc. which is all perfectly frugal. "Look I donated all my money for a computer running protein folding simulations."

No, those cultures tend to become "work is my status" cultures and go extinct. We have whole landscapes in europe, where protestants extremists roamed and they were so focused on working, they disappeared (farms merging into ever bigger farms) and the landscape then returned to wilderness.That sort of culture unchecked can eat itself until there is nothing left, but proud old people.

I kinda thought those protestant extremists moved to America and, um, built the most prosperous country in history.

Not all and this was mostly in the still medieval period. Without industrialization, all that work, just results in more work and no other reward but continued existence. Think thirty year war +

"work is my status" cultures tend to do very well economically, it's the "let it rot" counter cultures that they produce in subsequent generations that tend to collapse and collapse hard.

In recent times. Without a runaway industrialization, the best you can get is something like the amish- and then well they have still kids- but imagine them going on a prosperity gospel and high child mortality.. voila..

In short, no, not on its own. It can have a very rich economy, simply defined as having more then they need to survive (think of Switzerland), and it can operate in isolation, independent of anybody else, (think of any self sufficient island), in which case the frugal and/or religious nature of their culture is irrelevant, but to grow, by definition, means having more this year then last and that requires the creation of wealth.
There are only two ways to create wealth, debt and exploitation. Your frugal society is likely to frown on debt, especially if "preserving resources for the next generation" is important to them (debt not repaid now has to be repaid by the next generation) which leaves exploitation. Religion has not traditionally had any problems with exploitation but there has to be an 'other' to exploit. Whether it takes the form of an foreign markets, an underclass, colonisation or slave labour depends on what suits your storey best, but your culture can not have a growth economy on its own.
